# Visual Studio TFS/Git extensions global gitignore

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Where is it?  I assume there's one because it seems to ignore some VS stuff by default.

I've tried making changes to `%USERPROFILE%\global.gitignore` (which is the defualt for GitHub for Windows) as well as another one used by Git for Windows (mysysgit, don't ask), but neither seem to have any effect.

These "how-tos" don't mention a *global*, just configuring the *project* `.gitignore`

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh850445.aspx
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/01/30/getting-started-with-git-in-visual-studio-and-team-foundation-service.aspx

(Note: I'm using VS2012)

Comment: Not configurable yet, sorry.  We have a backlog item for this.

Comment: @EdwardThomson even if it's not configurable via VS, is it at least somewhere on the filesystem I can manually "fix"?  same with `.gitconfig` too, i suppose...